# How to isolate builds on Jenkins

Tags: git, maven, build, jenkins

We have Jenkins 1.538, maven 3 and git 1.7
There is a lot of branches. Also in maven we have about 7 builds. So the problem is that we run several builds on J simultaneously builds failed if we run it sequentially we failed. Example:

MultiJob1

build1.1 with profile default      from branch1

build1.2 with profile functional   from branch1

MultiJob2

build2.1 with profile default      from branch2

build2.2 with profile functional   from branch2

somebody push changes into branch1 and MultiJob1 is triggered build1.1 - built successfully. During building of build1.1 another developer push his changes to branch2 and Multijob2 triggers build2.1.

after build1.1 completed J triggers build1.2 but for some reason it take changes from branch2

as a result we get mysterious compilation error exceptions that we don't get locally and when we fire builds sequentially

What checkbox should I check to stop unpredictable behavior

I tried to use 'Disable automatic artifact archiving' and 'Delete workspace before build starts'
Hope that I explained it intelligible.

Comment: It sounds like your maven versions are not different on the branches. Jenkins makes relationships based on versions (in particular SNAPSHOT's). So you should have versions like `1.0-BRANCH1-SNAPSHOT` and `1.0-BRANCH2-SNAPSHOT`

Comment: Please provide more info on whether you are installing the artifacts to local repo and whether branches create different versions.

Answer (score 2):

In `Maven Build` configuration enable option:

- Use private Maven repository

Comment: How to make J share maven repository for build1,2 and 3. I see there 3 options: default, executor and workspace. What is workspace? and is there possibility to use custom workspace name

Comment: Do you want to share os isolate jobs? Im confused. There is option `Use custom workspace` in Jenkins. Also you can use option `Settings file` - `Settings file in filesystem` and configure workspace in flexible way.

Comment: I want to share workspace between builds inside MultiJob but isolate between different Multijobs

Comment: When you share builds, then always is possible to have unpredictable builds. Define your workspace inside locally defined `settings.xml`.